# Dynamic injection of collections into Spring managed beans

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, javabeans

How can I inject a collection into a spring bean dynamically. 
As I know 
Example of my Author class

```
import java.util.List;
public class Author {
private String name;
private List<String> listOfBooks;

public Author(String name, List<String> listOfBooks) {
    this.name = name;
    this.listOfBooks = listOfBooks;
}
public Author() {
}

public String getName() {
    return name;
}

public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}

public List<String> getListOfBooks() {
    return listOfBooks;
}

public void setListOfBooks(List<String> listOfBooks) {
    this.listOfBooks = listOfBooks;
}
 }
```

And my bean id is:

```
   <bean id="authorID" class="com.test.Author">
   </bean>
```

and some where I am using as `@AutoWired` bean for the Authors class.
And if I wants to add the books to the variable "listOfBooks".
How can I add it. is it by using reference to the Authors object and by accessing the getListOfBooks() method then adding the values. or is there any best way for this approach.
Thanks.

Comment: The creation of the `authorID` bean will fail, there is only a non default constructor present and the bean definition does not provide values for the name and the listOfBooks.

Answer (score 1):

```
 <property name="addressList">
     <list>
        <value>Book1</value>
        <value>Book2</value>
        <value>Book3</value>
        <value>Book4</value>
     </list>
  </property>
```

In you context file.

For more information please see this [post](http://www.mkyong.com/spring/spring-collections-list-set-map-and-properties-example/)

Answer (score 1):

Some more detail explanation:

```
 <property name="bookList">
     <list>
        <value>Java</value>
        <value>C++</value>
     </list>
  </property>
```

This way we are Passing bean reference for java.util.List

Remember: To use above bean definition, you need to define your setter methods in such a way that they should be able to handle references as well.

```
 ApplicationContext context = 
             new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("YourBeans.xml");

      Author a=(Author)context.getBean("authorID");

      a.getListOfBooks();
```

Your Getter and Setter will be:

```
public void setListOfBooks(List<String> bookList) {
    this.listOfBooks = bookList;
}
```

Also change getter accordingly.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

[Spring Injecting Collection](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/spring/spring_injecting_collection.htm) here you can get an idea of injecting  all types of collection [`list,set,map`] and `array`, and it's values as a primitive/reference